# Proof regarding a property of "$q$-ary" lattices

Tags: lattice-crypto

In this question we are dealing with "$q$-ary" lattices. I will give the definition available to me and I'm interested in proving the lemma. As a reference see the [PDF](https://github.com/cpeikert/LatticesInCryptography/blob/main/lec12.pdf) on page 2 from Peikert's lectures.

**Definition**. Let $\mathbb{Z}_q := \{ 0, 1, \dots, q-1\}$. We define $ \Lambda^{\perp}(\mathbf{A}) := \left\{ \mathbf{z} \in \mathbb{Z^m} : \mathbf{Az = 0} \right\} $, where $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{Z}_q^{n \times m}$

**Lemma**. Let $\mathbf{H} \in \mathbb{Z}_{q}^{n \times n}$ be invertible. Then $\Lambda^{\perp}(\mathbf{HA}) = \Lambda^{\perp}(\mathbf{A}) $.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Thank's Daniel!

Comment: it is correct you can close the question

Comment: Really the OP should factor out their proof from the question, and answer their own question with that answer.

Comment: Didn't you post this question on Math SE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the comments confirming that my proof is correct. As suggested in the comments, I'm happy to answer the question myself.

**Proof**:

$\Lambda^{\perp}(\mathbf{HA}) \subset \Lambda^{\perp}(\mathbf{A}) $, let $\mathbf{z} \in \Lambda^{\perp}(\mathbf{HA})$ then $\mathbf{HAz = 0}$ and $H$ is invertible implies $\mathbf{H^{-1}HAz = 0}$ and this implies $\mathbf{z} \in \Lambda^{\perp}(\mathbf{A})$.

$\Lambda^{\perp}(\mathbf{A}) \subset \Lambda^{\perp}(\mathbf{HA}) $, let $\mathbf{z} \in \Lambda^{\perp}(\mathbf{A})$ then $\mathbf{Az = 0}$ and multiply by $\mathbf{H}$ implies $\mathbf{HAz = 0}$ and this implies $\mathbf{z} \in \Lambda^{\perp}(\mathbf{HA})$.